# Why don't banks offer a combined chequing and savings account option?

Tags: canada, savings-account, checking-account

A few Canadian banks offer a combined chequing and savings account — see beneath for a generic example. Most do not though.

A combined account seems better for the following reasons.

1. You must keep money in a chequing account, but they pay little to no interest.
2. Chequing accounts charge for overdrafts. My landlord deposits my pre-dated cheques monthly. A year ago, he cashed the check for Jan in Feb, thus cashing two cheques in Feb. I didn't notice he didn't cash the check for January during the month of January, thus my chequing account had NSF and I got charged for an overdraft.
3. It's annoying and unhandy to check every month if you have enough money in your chequing account, even if you set up automatic transfers.

Why don't some or all banks offer a combined arrangement as a convenience for customers?

---

[image: non-specific bank's offer for combined checking and savings account]

Comment: "A year ago, he cashed the check for Jan in Feb, thus cashing two cheques in Feb. I didn't notice he didn't cash in Feb, thus my Chequing had NSF".  It's **completely your fault** for not paying attention to your checking account and what checks are still outstanding.  (I once was also lax about it, and suffered many NSF charges, but accepted that it was my fault.)

Comment: Why businesses make product decisions isn't really within the scope of the site.  But, generally, the point of a savings account is to leave cash idle.  The bank has to plan it's capital which is why savings accounts earn interest while checking or other spending accounts don't.

Comment: @RonJohn Don't you think I know? You didn't get my point.

Comment: That "combined" account is nothing but a high-interest savings chequing account.  And with fees like $1.50 for ABM withdrawal, $1 for debit card purchase and $1 for bill payment, they can afford to pay 1.25%.

Comment: In the US, there are regulations which limit number of withdrawals from a savings account, and which define the nature of reserves required to be held for various account types, likely regulations exist in Canada as well.

Comment: @RonJohn: On the other hand, those fees are waived if you maintain a balance of $1000 (or above, I presume). Which people who actually keep their savings in the account would probably do anyway.

Comment: Perspective from the US -- 1.25% is not a *high* interest rate.

Comment: To the close voters:  This is not a product or service recommendation question.  A product or service recommendation question would be something like "Which bank should I open an account with?"  This question is as on-topic for Personal Finance as they come.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn’t really anything special about this “combined savings/checking account.” It is just a checking account, one that happens to have, for the moment, a higher-than-average interest rate associated with it. The “combined account” terminology is just a marketing gimmick.

With any bank/credit union, there is nothing stopping you from putting all your money in your checking account and either closing the savings account or just leaving a small deposit in it to keep it open.

With any account, you need to look at the entire feature/interest rate/fee schedule to evaluate whether it is a good fit for you, and realize that the interest rate, fees, and even account features/services can change at any time. In my opinion, when it comes to my checking account, I prefer a credit union with low fees and great customer service, even if I get a lower interest rate return on my balance.

Comment: I'll note that many banks offer to link your accounts so that an overdraft on your checking account gets charged to your savings account instead. This actually isn't always good, since if a fraudster starts draining your checking account, it will also keeps withdrawing from savings until that depletes as well.

Comment: @pboss3010 Also, they usually charge you a penalty/fee every time they automatically move money between your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a glance on the OP said [bank account charges](https://repsourcepublic.manulife.com/wps/wcm/connect/62fb3693-ac18-47ee-a940-92fcdd1bc7d3/bnk_dep_AB0178.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CACHEID=ROOTWORKSPACE-62fb3693-ac18-47ee-a940-92fcdd1bc7d3-mdun6x2) and small print, I think OP just didn't realise there are pitfalls awaiting while not fixing the problem. Worst, the said merged account doesn't prevent potential overdraft but also incurred an 21% APR when it happens.

Most of the local bank that maintains a good account relationship with the client will inform the client before the overdraft. Today, some bank may even offer mobiles that notify the user on account activities. So I think OP should aim for the bank that provides such services than a merging account service that doesn't fix the problem.